# Clock divider code doesn't work with my counter, not sure why

Tags: vhdl

I have VHDL code for a clock divider and I'm trying to get it to work with my counter code. For some reason the clock divider doesn't output to the counter, it's strange because I've used the clock divider for another project and it works fine. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

TOP LEVEL:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity Counter is
    Port ( 
        Clock: in STD_LOGIC; -- Clock divider input signal
          Reset: in STD_LOGIC; --reset input      
          output: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0)); -- output        
end Counter;

ARCHITECTURE structural of Counter IS

 COMPONENT Mod_28_Counter IS
 PORT (
           clk: in STD_LOGIC; -- from the clock divider
              Reset: in STD_LOGIC;        
              output: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0));
 END COMPONENT;

  COMPONENT Clock_Divider IS
 PORT (
            Clock     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            Reset     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            output : OUT    STD_LOGIC);
 END COMPONENT;

 signal wire : STD_LOGIC;

 Begin
--With divider, does not work
U1: Mod_28_Counter port map (clk => wire, Reset => Reset, output => output); 
--This shows the counter works without the divider
--U1: Mod_28_Counter port map (clk => Clock, Reset => Reset, output => output);

U2: Clock_Divider port map (Clock => Clock, Reset => Reset, output => wire); 
 end structural; --
```

MOD COUNTER:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all; 

entity Mod_28_Counter is
    Port (           
           clk: in STD_LOGIC; -- from the clock divider
              Reset: in STD_LOGIC;        
              output: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0));
end Mod_28_Counter;

architecture Behavioral of Mod_28_Counter is

begin
  process(clk,Reset)                                   
    variable temporary:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0):="00000";
      begin
        if(Reset='1') then temporary:="00000"; 
          elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then 
              temporary:=temporary+1;
        if(temporary="11100") then temporary:="00000";
        end if;
        end if; 

      output<=temporary;
 end process;  
end Behavioral;
```

CLOCK DIVIDER:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity Clock_Divider is
    GENERIC(LIMIT : integer := 2); 
    PORT (
            Clock     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            Reset     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            output : OUT    STD_LOGIC
          );
end Clock_Divider;

architecture Behavioral of Clock_Divider is
signal count : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
begin

clkdiv: process (Clock, Reset)                      
     begin
        if rising_edge(Clock) then
            if Reset = '1' then 
                count <= (others => '0');
                output <= '0';
            elsif count = LIMIT-1 then
                count <= (others => '0');
                output <= '1';
            else
                count <= count+1;
                output <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
     end process; 
end Behavioral;
```

TEST BENCH:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity Counter_TB is
end Counter_TB;

architecture Behavioral of Counter_TB is
component Counter
port (
        Clock: in STD_LOGIC; -- Clock divider input signal
          Reset: in STD_LOGIC; --reset input      
          output: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0)); -- output  

end component;
signal Reset,Clock: STD_LOGIC;
signal output:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);

begin
dut: Counter port map (Clock => Clock, Reset => Reset, output=> output);

clockpro :process 
begin
     Clock <= '0';
     wait for 10 ns;
     Clock <= '1';
     wait for 10 ns;
end process;

main :process  
begin
Reset <= '0';
wait;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: `I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.`  Try using the reset. x"UUUUUUUU" (the default value of count) + 1 is x"XXXXXXXX". (You don't provide a specifc problem in your question either.)

Comment: Yup! With the default LIMIT = 2 and [an added reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLgF8.jpg).